# Download Package Documents Using NPM

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

After spending months in js/ts/nodejs developing I am wondering that there is no document file to review code signature in packages. I have searched for a way to download a document file in NPM but haven't found any command. Is there any way to download a document file in NPM?